# About elasticsearch-php fulltext search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I had a test like this:
My env:

```
elasticsearch-php:v2.3.0
elasticsearch-server: v1.7.1
message field text:"GET /index.php?type=bapapapahhh HTTP/1.1" 200 4906
```

PHP code:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['172.1.1.6:9200'])->build();

        $params = [
            'type' => 'nginx-80',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            ['match' => ['message' => 'papapahhh']],
                            //['prefix' => ['message' => 'bapapapah']],
                            //['fuzzy' => ['message' => 'bapapa']],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

$result = $client->search($params);
```

The question is that if keyword is 'bapapapahhh' message can be matching

But, if keyword is 'bapapapah',message can`t be matched

I tryed user  match prefix and others,But the result isn`t right.

Now,I want message field matching what set the keyword like 'papa','hhh','bapa','bapapa'.

thanks.